# Can i create a ggplot with two y variables, both geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a `ggplot` with two y variables. Both as columns, side by side.
Here is attempt with `iris`:

```
irissum= iris%>%
  group_by(Species)%>%
  summarise(across(contains("."),  mean))

ggplot(irissum, aes(x= Species))+
  geom_col(aes(y= Petal.Width), fill = "blue")+
  geom_col(aes(y = Petal.Length), fill = "red")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Petal width", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~.*1,name = "Petal length"))
```

This produces

[image]

But the `Petal.Width` columns are hidden. I tried adding `position= "dodge"` but that didn't help.
How do I produce a chart with two columns side by side, for each `Species`? Also, in my real data, the scales are quite different, is there are way to deal with that, as the `trans` argument isn't helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is pivoting the data longer, filtering to the columns we want, then using a combination of selecting the fill based on the column name, and `position = dodge` to adjust the horizontal position of the columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),  mean), .by = Species) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(variable %in% c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Species, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Petal.Width" = "blue", "Petal.Length" = "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Petal width", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans= ~.*1,name = "Petal length"))
```

Output:

[image: plot]